# Trying to update a contact field if that contact is added to the contact roles related list on an oppt'y

Tags: contact, opportunitycontactrole

Here is my scenario.
At my non-profit client, they enter opportunity records beneath the Account record.
They then add the specific Contact they are working with, beneath the contact roles related list.

They are asking if a given value is chosen from a Picklist on the opportunity, then a checkbox on the Contact record will be checked on.

I've attempted this with workflow, process builder, but have struck out.

Is this possible - any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Since no triggers are active on the Contact Role object, what I have done before is write a batch that runs daily/hourly/etc that looks at all the contact records modified in the appropriate timeframe and update the contact records accordingly

Comment: Welcome to the community.  You should be able to accomplish this with a Trigger on the Opportunity to traverse the relationship to the Contacts and then set the values on the associated Contacts.

Comment: Is your client using the NPSP? Have OpportunityContactRoles been enabled? That connects Contacts with Opportunities. It sounds from your description as though they're selecting a contact from the Account Related Contact List and want related contacts to appear on their Opportunities as well. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with a Trigger on the Opportunity to traverse the relationship to the Contacts and then set the values on the associated Contacts.

I do not believe any of the standard Admin tools can do this besides [Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_designer_flow_create.htm) which will only be useful in certain circumstances.